# Не работает Autoplay в тэге video на iOS

Tags: ios, html5, видео

Шапка на моем сайте сделана в виде короткого ролика, заключенного в тэг video, повторяется 1 раз, запускается автоматически с помощью атрибута autoplay.
Сейчас обнаружил, что iOS не поддерживает autoplay.
Подскажите, как заставить устройства с iOS проигрывать шапку автоматически?

Answer (score 1):

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled.

Перевод

> В Safari на iOS (для всех устройств, включая iPad) в случаях, когда пользователь может использовать мобильного оператора, который взимает плату за передачу данных, предварительная загрузка и автоматическое воспроизведение отключены.

[Источник](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html).

Comment: Да, но ведь существуют методы, с помощью которых можно обмануть систему?